# Web accessibility - focus items

Tags: html, css, accessibility, focus, wai-aria

I am working on a website, making it accessible. But I am having some trouble with the voice reader focus going into the items located in the footer.
I tried using aria-label but it didn't work.
I'll attach an image. 
The elements enter focus, which I can tell because of the blue ring around the item, but I don't know how to get the orange ring to focus to those anchor elements in the footer.
[image: voice over focus in the element above while the regular focus is in the item in the footer]

Comment: Hi, we need to see your CSS to give a definitive answer but my guess is your orange focus indicator has a class that is tied to the `<main>` element and your footer is a `<footer>` element (either that or tied to a class on the main content that doesn't affect the footer if your site uses `<divs>` instead of regions). If you want to share your URL in the comments I can have a look for you. Also don't use orange for your focus indicator if you are working on accessibility, it will not have sufficient colour contrast for WCAG as orange has poor contrast with white.

Comment: If you want to fix it yourself, try searching your CSS for ":focus" and see what classes come up. Or you can also try Right Click -> Inspect (on an element that can receive focus and has the styles you want) -> Elements in the developer tools window and in the right panel that says 'Styles' you have an option at the top that says `:hov`. If you click that a panel will appear that says "force element state" -> choose ":focus" and then look at the styles that are listed, you will see one that adds your orange border and you can see how the classes are structured

Comment: I would really appreciate your help. The orange ring is generate by chromebox classic extension. Therefore I don't think I can change it. I also don't think It is a class that is tied to the <main> element. Since the nav code is being focus and read properly .

Comment: HERE IS THE LINK TO MY PROJECT, to the sass file for the portfolio page specifically: https://github.com/anthonyarguello96/Website/blob/staticWebsite/sass/extra.scss @GrahamRitchie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was created due to the use of "fontawesome.com" for the social media Icons. In order to include an alternative text or label to the element (provide by fontawesome.com) you need to use a different method: In my specific case this solved it:

```
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/iamthonystark/" aria-label="Instagram">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i>
</a>
```

Here is the link to this solution and the solution to other possible issues related to accessibility and fontawesome.com

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility

Comment: ah i misunderstood the focus problem, sorry to lead you down the wrong path I thought it was a styling issue I didn't realise the orange focus ring was from the screen reader.